# How to Interpret Bulk API UpsertResult element?

Tags: bulk-api, upsert

Below is the Result of the Bulk API job(batch) I submitted :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
    <result>
        <errors>
            <fields>MailingStateCode</fields>
            <message>A country/territory must be specified before specifying a state value for field: Mailing State/Province Code</message>
            <statusCode>FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <success>false</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
</results>
```

If there is a clear error with the state code, why is it still creating the record (value true for created element in the response)? What am I missing here?

Because the value for created element is true in the response, I tried to find the record in the system but I don't see.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_upsert_upsertresult.htm -- I have gone through this link but still not clear on how to interpret the above result.

**Note:** I am sending only one record for the whole Bulk Job and doing this through ETL tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `created` attribute simply tells you if the record was chosen for insert (created is true) or update (created is false). The `success` attribute tells you if the operation actually succeeded.

Here's a matrix that explains this:

```
                | created = true | created = false |
----------------+----------------+-----------------+
success = true  |    inserted    |     updated     |
----------------+----------------+-----------------+
success = false |     error      |      error      |
----------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

I feel that this is a rather clumsy name choice, as created should really be something like `operation` with the two choices of `insert` or `update`.

All you need to remember is that if success is false, no record has been created or updated. The created attribute simply tells you which DML mode the system chose for that record.